# Laravel: Preencher formulário com form::model

Tags: laravel

Utilizo o mesmo formulário para cadastrar e editar, por isso tenho aquele `if else` para mostrar o *form*. Como tenho a tabela `Convenio` e `Endereco`, preciso trazer as informações do endereco através de um `with`, a minha dúvida é como preencher o formulário automaticamente com essas informações.

Os dados referentes a tabela `Convenio`, são preenchidos normalmente, mas o da tabela com `with` não. Ali no form::model se eu trocar o `$convenio` por `$convenio->endereco`, preenche os campos referente a essa tabela, mas não preenche os campos da tabela convenio.

Teria alguma forma de colocar a variável `$convenio` e `$convenio->endereco` juntas ali no *form*? Tentei alguns jeitos, mas não funcionaram.

Se eu deixar o nome dos *input* como *array*, como `endereco[rua]`, funciona, porém da erro na hora de cadastrar.

CONTROLLER

```
$convenio = Convenio::with('endereco')
                        ->with('telefones')
                        ->find($id);

$cidades = Cidade::pluck('nomeCidade', 'id');

$servicos = Servico::pluck('nomeServ', 'id')->all();

$title = 'Editar convênio';

return view('painel.convenio.create-edit', compact('convenio', 'cidades', 'servicos', 'title'));
```

VIEW

```
@if(isset($convenio))
            {!! Form::model($convenio, ['route' => ['convenio.update', $convenio->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}
        @else
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'convenio.store']) !!}
        @endif
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    {!! Form::label('nome', 'Nome') !!}
                    {!! Form::input('text', 'nome', null, ['id' => 'nome', 'placeholder' => 'Nome do convênio', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::label('cidade', 'Cidade') !!}
                {{ Form::select('id_cidade', $cidades, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'cidade']) }}
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::label('rua', 'Rua') !!}
                {!! Form::input('text', 'rua', null, ['id' => 'rua', 'placeholder' => 'Rua', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::label('numero', 'Número') !!}
                {!! Form::input('text', 'numero', null, ['id' => 'numero', 'placeholder' => 'Número', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::label('sala', 'Sala') !!}
                {!! Form::input('text', 'sala', null, ['id' => 'sala', 'placeholder' => 'Sala', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                {!! Form::label('fone', 'Telefone') !!}
            </div>

            <div class="fones">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input id="fone" type="text" name="fone[]" placeholder="Telefone" class="form-control fone">
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="btn remover">Remover</a>
            <a class="btn adicionar">Adicionar</a>
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::label('servico', 'Tipo de serviço') !!}
                {!! Form::select('id_servico', [null => 'Selecione o tipo de serviço'] + $servicos, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'servico']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::label('especialidades', 'Tipo de especialidade') !!}
                <select name="id_especialidade" id="especialidades" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Selecione o tipo de serviço</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                {!! Form::label('descricao', 'Informações adicionais') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('descricao', null, ['id' => 'descricao', 'placeholder' => 'Informações adicionais', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        {!! Form::submit('Salvar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

        <a href="{{route('convenio.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Voltar</a>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: já pensou em utilizar `null ?: $convinio->endereco->rua` ao inves de apenas `null` ?

Comment: Já tinha pensando nisso, mas queria alguma solução q modificasse somente o form e já preenchesse automático, sem precisar modificar os inputs.

Comment: Não há como. O FMB (Form Model Bind) se baseia em chave/valor. Então cada input vai conter o valor correspondente a chave associada a ele. No caso rua tu manda para Endereco (acredito ser outro Model). O que tu pode tentar, eu nunca fiz desta forma, é usar 'convenio.endereco.rua' e etc... nos campos que há relacionamento com o model Endereço.